# Javamail reading mail from exchange works in localhost but not when hosted on server

Tags: java, web-services, email, jakarta-mail

I am successfully able to read and delete mails using javamail when trying from localhost but when I deploy the java code on server and try to call the service, it gets stuck at     store.connect(pop3Host, user, password);

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "hostname", port 995, isSSL true


Here are the properties added:

    Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            //  properties.put("mail.imap.host", pop3Host);
            //  properties.put("mail.imap.port", 143);
            //  properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", true);
                properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
                properties.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "ExchangeSSLSocketFactory");
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "ExchangeSSLSocketFactory");
                Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
                 emailSession.setDebug(true);
                // create the POP3 store object and connect with the popserver
                Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
                store.connect(pop3Host, user, password);

                // create the folder object and open it
                Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Comment: Connect to your server via ssh and check, if your `pop3host` is reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a firewall preventing you from connecting directly, requiring you to connect through a [proxy server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).

Also, you probably [don't need the special socket factory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  And you're using the "pop3s" protocol but setting properties for the "pop3" protocol.  It's probably simpler if you just use the "pop3" protocol and set the "mail.pop3.ssl.enable" property.  You won't need the starttls property if you're connecting with SSL to begin with.